# how to call php in html file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

anybody please help me with this, I've been stuck with this for a week
This is my coding

**attandance_kehadiran_saya.html**

```
<div id="pages_maincontent"> 
<!-- today attandance --> 
<div id="kehadiransaya" name="kehadiransaya"></div> 
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">   $(document).ready(function()   
{
    $.ajax(
    {
      url: 'php/attendance_kehadiran_saya.php',
      type: 'POST', 
      async: false,
      success: function(data)
      {
          $("#kehadiransaya").html(data);
      }
    });   }); </script>
```

**attendance_kehadiran_saya.php**

```
<div id="wrapper">
        <div class="row row-inline-block small-spacing">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="box-content">
                    <h4 class="box-title"></h4>
                    <!-- /.box-title -->
                    <!-- /.dropdown js__dropdown -->
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table">
                            <thead> 
                                <tr> 
                                    <th>Masa</th> 
                                    <th>Jenis</th>
                                    <th>Tujuan</th> 
                                </tr> 
                            </thead> 
                            <tbody> 
                                <tr> 
                                <?php
                                $q_attendance = $cls_waa->kehadiransaya($id, $date);
                                foreach($q_attendance as $r_attendance)
                                {
                                    $wa_time_in = $r_attendance['wa_time_in'];
                                    $wa_time_out = $r_attendance['wa_time_out'];

                                ?>

                                    <td><?php echo $wa_time_in; ?></td> 
                                    <td><?php echo $wa_time_out; ?></td> 
                                </tr>  
                                <?php } ?>
                            </tbody> 
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.box-content -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.col-xs-12 -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.row row-inline-block small-spacing -->           
    <!-- /.main-content -->
</div>
```

suppose at my html page, php page will replace there, but it not, without showing any error. Can anybody help me please

Comment: How do you know there's no error when you have no ajax error handler? Why a post with no data? Never ever use `async: false` it is a terrible practice and is deprecated

Comment: What are `$cls_waa`, `$id` and `$date`? If you expect a help, you have to post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also your `<tr>` open tag is not in the loop!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be that you are **POSTing** to a PHP page where you are trying to **retrieve** data from. Considering you're not passing any JavaScript variables, instead of using AJAX at all, why not simply echo the contents of the PHP page into the DIV you want in the HTML itself?

Assuming `attendance_kehadiran_saya.php` displays the exact output that you want to inject as **part** of `attandance_kehadiran_saya.html`, inside the `kehadiransaya` div, just change `attandance_kehadiran_saya.html` to:

```
<div id="pages_maincontent"> 
  <!-- today attandance --> 
  <div id="kehadiransaya" name="kehadiransaya">
    <?php include('attendance_kehadiran_saya.php'); ?>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: but if i use that method, i must save my file as attandance_kehadiran_saya.php. i need to save my file as .html since after ompleting this, i need to convert it into apk for mobile used

Comment: That is something that you should have certainly specified in your question. PHP files **cannot** run in an APK, as they are **server-side**. What you need is a server to host `attendance_kehadiran_saya.php`, and then inside `attendence_kehadiran_saya.html` use AJAX with `type: 'GET'` to reference the PHP file on the server, much like you were doing before. The only difference is basically that you need `GET` instead of `POST`.